# How to Add Data Contents to Data Grid in the Same Page without any Database Connectivity?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Say, I have a TextBox - When the User enters contents into TextBox and Click on Add the Content Should Populate in the DataGrid Without any db connectivity.  The User Can add repeated items in the TextBox and Click on Add, So Every Value gets Popluated in the Grid.
How do I achieve this?

Comment: you can use the List<> generic class and bind it to your DataGrid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this, first you have to Imports the *System.Collection.Generic* namespace

```
 private List<string> addContent(string content)
{
    //create a generic list of string type
    List<string> s = new List<string>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        s.Add(content);
    }
    return s;
}

protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //Passed the List<> as DataSource and then bind the content in the list<> in the  DataGrid
    this.DataGrid1.DataSource = this.addContent(this.txtadd.Text);
    this.DataGrid1.DataBind();

}
```

I Hope this works for you